# Calculating the trace of a large sparse matrix

Tags: python, c++, scipy

I have a sparse large matrix (linear dimension of 2*10^6) for which I want to calculate its trace.
Calculating it brute force takes 16 seconds to access each diagonal element (hence I could do it in a YEAR!).

I was thinking of saving it to the disk using scipy.io.mmwrite and reading it with a c++ code which should be much faster. However I cannot find any package that could help me do that.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: What format is it in?

Comment: it's a csc_matrix

Comment: 16 seconds is in python ?

Comment: per element, yes.

Comment: That portage in C++ is not ok for you ? https://github.com/uestla/Sparse-Matrix

Comment: I'd need to load a matrix in some format generated by Python...

Comment: What is the sparsity of this matrix ? ( number of assigned elements)

Comment: How is this matrix saved? You could load chunks in memory and use it as a numpy array to just calculate the [trace](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.trace.html), which is very fast

Comment: Before I save it to the HD it’s stored on the RAM. Regarding scarcity I would say ~ 16%.

Comment: Does `M.diagonal().sum()` work?

Comment: Did you check if your Python programme is not paging too much?

Comment: Doing `M[i,i]` for a large sparse matrix can be expensive.  Index access to sparse matrices is not as simple or fast as with dense arrays.

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj, it worked. I was not aware that you can slice a csc_matrix this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was as simple as: np.array(Mat.diagonal()).sum()

Thanks @hpaulj !